Purpose of big size resistor in pcb
I dismantled a toaster and tried to figure out the purpose of every component.
The heater elements of the toaster forms a voltage divider that gives around 20VAC to the PCB. Then a diode and a cap makes it DC. I don't understand what is the purpose of the big resistor of 56Ω named R1 in the schematics.



It is there to control the initial inrush of current and is probably also fusible to protect against a short on the PCB.
If I understand the circuit you're describing, if the main switch is closed at the peak of the AC cycle, a full 20V from the heating element divider would be applied at the diode.  Without the resistor, the full 20V would be applied across the diode. If it survived, it would pump a tremendous amount of current into that poor little (literally little!) capacitor.  Even if the switch was closed at a zero point, the current needed to charge the capacitor in that first half cycle would almost certainly exceed the diode and capacitor ratings without the resistor as a limiter.
The resistor needs to have a relatively small value to limit the rectifier voltage sag.  At the same time, it needs to be pretty bulky to handle a worst-case inrush.  It's probably also a fusible resistor in case the capacitor or some other part of PCB shorts out.  (While far from universal, fusible resistors often have a grey body, like this one.)

It limits the current from the voltage divider, which could otherwise be quite high (a 1500W toaster on 120VAC would draw about 12A, so the current to charge the electrolytic capacitor could be quite high, or traces could even be damaged). A short on the PCB could result in almost 12A flowing in traces that would quickly heat to red heat.
It may also act as a fuse (it is similar in appearance to other fusible resistors), so it limits the effect of any failures after that point, which would probably speed regulatory approvals, if nothing else.
This is one of the few applications (hair dryers being another) where using a voltage divider to create a low-voltage power supply from the mains actually makes sense, since the power is being used anyway to toast the food. A designer who used a 1500W voltage divider to power a low voltage 1-2W circuit rather than a compact off-line switcher (or a simple mains-frequency transformer) would probably be out the door quickly.

Big resistors can handle a lot of power, it's likely that this is a power resistor for dissipating power in the design. Another reason for large resistors is clearance and creepage and physically distancing the terminals on the PCB to prevent arcing.
